# Symfony PHPUnit tests issue

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7.2, symfony-4.3

I have the following issue while running PHPUnit test cases in Symfony. I have tried removing various tests cases which could cause memory issues but no luck. is it something related to  PHP VERSION i.e. 7.2.20?

> $ phpdbg -qrr ./bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
> --coverage-html $CI_PROJECT_DIR/codecoverage/ --coverage-clover $CI_PROJECT_DIR/clover.xml --log-junit $CI_PROJECT_DIR/junit.xml  -c .
> PHPUnit 7.5.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Testing Project Test Suite F.......FF.FF. [PHP Warning:  Uncaught
> ErrorException:
> include(/builds/development/project/project-docs/var/cache/test/pools/yZJnsPMs0T/S/6/+yyw-9cjArnMASkmxItg):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /builds/development/project/project-docs/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/PhpFilesTrait.php:114
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /builds/development/project/project-docs/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/PhpFilesTrait.php(114):
> Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PhpFilesAdapter::Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter{closure}(2,
> 'include(/builds...', '/builds/develop...', 114, Array)
>
> #1 /builds/development/project/project-docs/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/PhpFilesTrait.php(114):
> include()
>
> #2 /builds/development/project/project-docs/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/AbstractAdapterTrait.php(51):
> Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PhpFilesAdapter->doFetch(Array)
>
> #3 /builds/development/project/project-docs/vendor/symfony/cache/Adapter/TraceableAdapter.php(77):
> Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\AbstractAdapte in
> /builds/development/project/project-docs/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/PhpFilesTrait.php
> on line 114] [PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 702808064)
> (tried to allocate 140362191340481 bytes) in
> /builds/development/project/project-docs/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/PhpFilesTrait.php
> on line 114]

I also tried `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an issue with PHP 7.2.20 and 7.3.7

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/990

The solution will be implemented in the next release of PHP, but for now there is no solution on those version, ideally avoid these versions.